# Deriving vertical circular cone parameters from a set of points

Tags: geometry

I want to find parameters - the apex (x0,y0,z0) and the aperture t - of a 3D circular cone with axis parallel to the vertical axis, given four 3D points (x1,y1,z1),...,(x4,y4,z4) on its surface. Four parameters suggest that four 3D points should be enough to find such a cone, however, I failed to solve the set of 4 equations. I would appreciate help.

Comment: Did you try to "build" with GeoGebra to demonstrate a solution? Do you want to build a right angle cone given 4 points on its surface?

Comment: I am not sure you can get a right angle cone when you specify 4 points. May be three?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build a right angle cone given 4 points on its surface. There are 4 parameters of the cone (3d apex position and the aperture), so I assumed 4 points are needed to build such a cone. I guess 3 points could be a part of more than one cone... I am not familiar with GeoGebra. I just opened it, but I am not sure yet how to demonstrate a solution with it.

Comment: In this paper https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01288325v2/document they give a way to find a solution for finding a (not necessarily vertical) right cone from 6 points. I've tried to use the method and was able to get a solution from 5 points for a vertical cone, but it seems wrong.